# Como exibir equações no Android?

Tags: android

Alguém sabe como fazer pra exibir equações matemáticas em aplicativos Android?

Por acaso existe alguma coisa como o Latex, onde eu coloco `$f(x) = \frac{x^3}{\sqr{x}}$` e ele mostre no TexView:

[image: Resultado Esperado]

Alguém sabe se existe uma forma nativa do Android para fazer isso ou uma biblioteca, ou um componente gráfico, qualquer coisa?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca  [jqmath](https://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) ela te permite usar formulas no android

Open the following website jqMath and download the JavaScript library. Once you have downloaded the library, copy and paste the folder in the asset folder of your application. If your application does not contain an asset folder, create one first before dropping the plugins to the folder.

Primeiro baixe a biblioteca no site, deposi de baixa cole na paste de assets:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizei no arquivo de html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=UnifrakturMaguntia">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mathscribe/jqmath-0.4.3.css">

    <script src="mathscribe/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="mathscribe/jqmath-etc-0.4.3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- <script>M.MathPlayer = false; M.trustHtml = true;</script> →
</head>
```

Crie uma webview com o arquivo:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="elearning.chidi.com.elearning.FormulaActivity">

 <WebView
        android:id="@+id/formula_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/more_options"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:background="@color/icons"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

por fim altere sua activity para chama a webview criada na tela:

```
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class NumberBasicsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private WebView articleContent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_basics);

        Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);
        topToolBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
        topToolBar.setLogoDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.logo_desc));
        articleContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.article);
        articleContent.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        articleContent.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        try {            
            articleContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/testfile.html");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_number_basics, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

O resultado final sera:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte:
https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-display-math-formula-and-equation-in-android-application/